# Jenkins Plugins Error After Update - "Errors Checking Update Site"

Tags: redhat, connection, jenkins

I'm running Jenkins on a **RHEL 7.9** server, with **OpenJDK 11.0.17**.  I recently updated Jenkins to version **2.361.4** from **2.346.3**. After updating I went to the plugins manager page to see what plugins needed to be updated and I noticed the following:
[image]

If I click Check Now button nothing changes and the error message remains. I tried restarting services with no luck. The **jenkins.log** file in **/var/log/jenkins** doesn't contain anything useful either, see screenshot below:
[image]
[image]

The '**Advanced**' tab has the following URL provided which is accessible and returns values when I open it in a browser - https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json. I don't have any experience managing Jenkins upgrades so I'm learning as I go unfortunately.

Has anybody run into this issue before? A developer on my team was able to perform a build so the plugins seem to be working but the error is concerning and I'm not sure if further updates down the road could cause more headaches.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have set proxy for plugins.

That is

```
https://localhost/manage/pluginManager/advanced
```

It seems that jenkins tries to check plugins page, but proxy stops.

Although, I suppose it should timeout the connection not reset the connection, but well, advanced IT is like a magic, right?